# Can't find VBOs in the system settings

Tags: performance

I want to enable VBOs (Vertex Buffer Objects) but I can't find it anywhere in the User Preferences.

I wanted better performance when sculpting because it freezes with more than 500k polygon meshes

My specs are

- R9 280
- i5 6600k
- 16gb ddr4
- SSD 250gb
- 1Tb hard drive

Here is a screenshot

[image: my system settings]

Comment: Please post images with the tools here...it will then be displayed right with your question.

Comment: what tools do you mean?

Comment: Click "edit" below your question (to the right of the voting buttons), then click the image icon (should be like 6th from the left). You will see a dialog pop up...

Comment: ty i understood it now :D

Comment: it is not there: could it be this? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/system.html: "If your hardware does not support some of the options described on this page, then it will either not show up or get corrected on startup." at home I just can use 2.76 (old video card), but I can see the vbo checkbox there, just above "window draw method"...

Answer (score 3):

As of version 2.77 [the option seems to have been removed](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?394189-So-we-have-VBO-in-2-77rc1-enabled-by-default).

With the OpenGL version bump vertex arrays are no longer supported, so Vertex Buffer Object are always enabled by default as of commit [c402a379a23a](https://developer.blender.org/rBc402a379a23af71aa5c21566967b75ab5c869e01) so the option was removed from user preferences, [according to the release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/BGE#Raster_Storage).

Comment: can i enable this or smth similar for better performance>?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. For the Blender viewport VBOs are always enabled now. The two links in the answer refer to a new option to use VBOs in the game engine, which in the future will also be always enabled.

Comment: @brecht Thanks for the clarification, fixed my answer accordingly. Can you see if it is more accurate now? Feel free to edit if you feel something is still misleading, I am no developer so these things may escape my grasp.

Comment: Commit: https://developer.blender.org/rBc402a379a23af71aa5c21566967b75ab5c869e01